# What does a C++ address hex represent?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

The following `main()` is one of my attempts at decoding the significance of pointer values:

```
int main(){
    int a = 15, b = 27;
    int *p = &a, *q = &b;
    cout << p << ',' << q;
}
```

The two values printed are hexadecimals, namely `p = 0x28fef4, q = 0x28fef0`. These look like hex values, representing  `2686708` and `2686704` in decimal.

This raises some questions, of which you may answer as many as you like.

1. Why is `q` smaller than `p`? I would expect memory to be assigned in ascending order, but `q < p`.
2. Why do addresses rarely change? I ran a similar program a few hours ago, and I remember the address being `0x28fef4` that time too.
3. What does one unit in the hex value represent? A bit? A byte?
4. I have around 8 GB of memory (RAM). Why are the values of `p` and `q` so small compared to my RAM capacity?

Feel free to answer any or all of these questions, or to provide any related information about pointers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is q smaller than p? I would expect memory to be assigned in ascending order, but q < p.

I'm not sure why you'd expect that. What possible difference could it make?

> Why do addresses rarely change? I ran a similar program a few hours ago, and I remember the address being 0x28fef4 that time too.

Apparently your platform doesn't randomize stack addresses. Same stack, same addresses.

> What does one unit in the hex value represent? A bit? A byte?

A byte.

> I have around 8 GB of memory (RAM). Why are the values of p and q so small compared to my RAM capacity?

Physical memory has nothing to do with this. These are virtual memory addresses, not physical memory addresses.

Comment: I suppose I expected `q` > `p`, because I'm thinking of the addresses like a box, or a bucket. You fill up `0x28fef4` with `a`, and then put `b` on top of it, four bytes further up. I'm looking for the physical significance of the number `2686708`. If I'm thinking about this in the wrong way, what's the right way to think about it?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh One unit in the hex representation is 4 bits.  A byte is usually (but not always) 8 bits.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh One unit in the hex representation equates to four in the binary representation.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh The number is a byte address. It happens to be expressed in hex, but it could be expressed in decimal, octal, or any other method. It's still the same number.

Comment: @Johan: There's no particular significance to the numbers. The program allocates some memory for the stack, mapped into some part of the address space. This function uses part of that to store local variables. They'll be close together since they're in the same stack frame, but it's up to the compiler exactly where to put them.

Comment: @Johan: The bucket idea is partially right, except some compilers put in the bucket "upside down", so it's more like a stack of sticky notes hanging from the ceiling.  It works exactly the same, just starting high and "piling" down instead of piling upward.

Comment: Now that I think about it, the idea of filling up a stack off memory came from this program, noticing that the memory addresses were exactly four units away from eachother. Before, I assumed variables were assigned to random free spots.

Comment: @Johan Not variables on the stack, as these are.

Answer (score 0):

*I would expect memory to be assigned in ascending order*

This expectation is totally unfounded. Compilers don't order things according to their order of appearance in the source code or other insignificant details.

*Why do addresses rarely change?*

Similar pieces of source code are often translated to similar pieces of target code. What's so surprising here?

*What does one unit in the hex value represent? A bit? A byte?*

A byte (but please bear in mind that "hex value" is a misnomer, values are integers, the notation is hex).

*Why are the values of p and q so small*

Your variables are automatic, which is the C way of saying "they are on the stack". Your compiler allocates the stack near the beginning of virtual memory adddress space. Every program has its own virtual memory address space so it's OK when two programs that run at the same time occupy the same range of virtual addresses.